# Sorting and Combining datetime data frames Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, datetime

I am trying to combine `dates1` and `dates2` that combines the data frames sorts them in synchronous order. There are alike date values on both sets and the code should be able to only have one unique value in the output. what code will I need to get the `Expected Output` below?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

dates1 = pd.to_datetime(['2015-10-08 13:41:00', 
                 '2015-10-08 13:44:00', '2015-10-08 13:48:00',
                 '2015-10-08 13:49:00'])

dates2 = pd.to_datetime(['2015-10-08 13:42:00','2015-10-08 13:44:00', '2015-10-08 13:45:00', '2015-10-08 13:50:00'])
```

Expected output:

```
['2015-10-08 13:41:00',
 '2015-10-08 13:42:00', '2015-10-08 13:43:00',
 '2015-10-08 13:44:00', '2015-10-08 13:45:00',
 '2015-10-08 13:46:00', '2015-10-08 13:47:00',
 '2015-10-08 13:48:00', '2015-10-08 13:49:00',
 '2015-10-08 13:50:00', '2015-10-08 13:51:00']
```

Comment: where did `2015-10-08 13:43:00`, `2015-10-08 13:46:00`, `2015-10-08 13:47:00`, `2015-10-08 13:51:00` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they're both `pandas.DatetimeIndex`, you can use set operations from `pandas.Index`

```
dates1.union(dates2)
```

For multiple DatetimeIndex there are several options

```
dates1.union(dates2).union(dates3).union(dates4)
```

or a better approach

```
import functools
functools.reduce(pd.Index.union, [dates1, dates2, dates3, dates4])
```

or use the concat approach suggested by the other answer to this question

Comment: thank you that works if I had `dates3, dates4 .... etc` could I unify multiple dates groups as a whole

Comment: I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.concat([date1,date2]).drop_duplicates().sort_values()
```